# Disable Dialog positive button when none of the multiple choice is checked

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

**Scenario:** I want the positive button on a Dialog to remain inactive until user selects one of the options on check list. And Stay active otherwise.

Options of the checklist are set by `setMultiChoiceItems()`

Will `setOnItemSelectedListener(AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener listener)` help?

Thank you!

Comment: Try to use `custom-dialog` options.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
    alertDialog.getButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
```

But **IMPORTANT NOTE!**
You can only call that "getButton" method after calling "show()" for the dialog. If show haven't been called it will return **null**.